# Template is lost on pagination Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a site created in Drupal 6 and am having problems with a particular page.

The page uses a specific content type (type_a). This has it's own page template (page-type_a.tpl.php) This all works fine.

I've then added a view onto that page using views_embed_view(). This view has pagination.

The first page looks great (URL = /my-page), the template is right, the view appear and so does the pagination.

However when I select another page on the pagination the page reloads correctly (URL - /my-page?page=2) all the content is correct, the node data is there as is the new page of the view. However this page has now fallen back to the default page template.

Anyone know how I might get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add template suggestions in your `preprocess_page` function to have it always use any template for a chosen url.